# Ajax success function does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can someoone help me. My success function does not seem to work. The beforesend is working and i have checked the variable s. It is true before the ajax so all the validations are correct. Please have a look..

```
function enquiry_validations() {
    if (s) {
        var url = "http://localhost:9080/c/wp-content/themes/aussie/mailer.php";
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: "property_type=" + property_type + "&bedrooms=" + bedroom + "&bathroom=" + bathroom + "&condition=" + condition + "&est_size=" + est + "&parking=" + packing + "&special_feature=" + spl_fet + "&other=" + oth + "&unit_no=" + unt_no + "&street_no=" + street_no + "&street_name=" + street_name + "&studio=" + suburb + "&State=" + state + "&relation=" + relationship + "&purpose=" + purpose + "&cell=" + time_to_cell + "&currently_listed_n=" + currently_listed + "&first_name=" + first_name + "&sur_name=" + last_name + "&telephone=" + telephone + "&email=" + email,

            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log('happeneing');
                jQuery('#ajax-loader').show();
                jQuery('#ajax-loader').html('<img src="http://localhost:9080/c/wp-content/themes/aussie/images/ajax-loader.gif">');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                jQuery('#ajax-loader').hide();
                console.log(result);

                if (result == '0') {
                    console.log("No Result")
                }
                if (result == '1') {
                    jQuery.fancybox('<div class="aussi-en-pop"><h3>Thank you for using Northern Property Reports.</h3> <p>Your Northern Reports representative is busy getting your Property Report ready and will be in touch within 48 hours with your free report. <br> All enquiries please email :  <a href="mailto:info@northernpropertyreports.com.au">info@northernpropertyreports.com.au</a></p></div>');
                    jQuery("#Property_type").val('');
                    jQuery('#bedrooms').val('');
                    jQuery('#bathrooms').val('');
                    jQuery('#condition').val('');
                    jQuery('#est').val('');
                    jQuery('#parking').val('');
                    jQuery("input[type='checkbox']#chk:checked").prop('checked', false);
                    jQuery('#oth').val('');
                    jQuery('#un_no').val('');
                    jQuery('#Street_no').val('');
                    jQuery('#street_name').val('');
                    jQuery('#suburb').val('');
                    jQuery('#state').val('');
                    jQuery('#relationship_to_Property').val('');
                    jQuery('#purpose_of_request').val('');
                    jQuery('#time_to_sell').val('');
                    jQuery("input[type='radio']:checked").prop('checked', false);;
                    jQuery('#first_name').val('');
                    jQuery('#last_name').val('');
                    jQuery('#telephone').val('');
                    jQuery('#email').val('');
                    jQuery('#confirm_email').val('');
                    jQuery("input[type='checkbox']#agree:checked").prop('checked', false);
                    console.log("YES Result")
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What does not work? Are there error messages? What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: Open Developer tools (w/e browser you're using), switch to Network tab, refresh the page, make your function run and post the response code of this request. Is it 200 or something else?

Comment: Thankyou very much for replying. The problem i am facing is the ajax is being executed till before send but the success function isnt being executed. I know this because i see
       console.log('happeneing');

in the developer tools but i dont see 
       console.log(result);
There is no error since the error function is not showing any errors. In the networks tab i see the XML data being parsed by the name mailer.php ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Perhaps posting your PHP script will better help us understand the problem, but, for starters...*

I noticed this:

```
data: "property_type=" + property_type + "&bedrooms=" + bedroom + "&bathroom=" + bathroom + "&condition=" + condition + "&est_size=" + est + "&parking=" + packing + "&special_feature=" + spl_fet + "&other=" + oth + "&unit_no=" + unt_no + "&street_no=" + street_no + "&street_name=" + street_name + "&studio=" + suburb + "&State=" + state + "&relation=" + relationship + "&purpose=" + purpose + "&cell=" + time_to_cell + "&currently_listed_n=" + currently_listed + "&first_name=" + first_name + "&sur_name=" + last_name + "&telephone=" + telephone + "&email=" + email,
```

May I suggest:

```
data: {
        'data': {
            'property_type': property_type,
            'bedrooms': bedroom,
            'bathroom': bathroom,
            'condition': condition
         }
},
```

And on the PHP script:

```
<?php
   $data = array();
   $response = array();

   if(isset($_POST['data']) {
       $data = $_POST['data'];
       $response['code'] = "200";
       $response['message'] = "Hi! The property type is " . $data['property_type'];
   }

  echo json_encode($response);
```

And on your `success` function:

```
success: function( response ) {
    if(response.message) {
        console.log(response.message);
    }
}
```

Also, from the [jQuery.ajax() API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> **Deprecation Notice**: The **`jqXHR.success()`**, **`jqXHR.error()`**, and **`jqXHR.complete()`** callbacks are deprecated as of **jQuery 1.8**. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use **`jqXHR.done()`**, **`jqXHR.fail()`**, and **`jqXHR.always()`** instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {"property_type": property_type ,
          "bedrooms": bedroom,
          "bathroom" : bathroom ,
          "condition" : condition ,
          "est_size" : est ,
          "parking" : packing ,
          "special_feature" : spl_fet ,
          "other" : oth ,
          "unit_no" : unt_no ,
          "street_no" : street_no ,
          "street_name" : street_name ,
          "studio" : suburb ,
          "State" : state ,
          "relation" : relationship ,
          "purpose" : purpose ,
          "cell" : time_to_cell ,
          "currently_listed_n" : currently_listed ,
          "first_name" : first_name ,
          "sur_name" : last_name ,
          "telephone" : telephone ,
          "email" : email}
```

Use this format to send or pass the data from jquery